# Multiple file transfer on persistent tcp using python

Tags: python-3.x, sockets

I am trying to transfer multiple images over the persistent TCP connection in python. According to my knowledge, this code should work fine but sometimes it shows the following error ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '6789:'

For each image, I am first trying to send the size of that image to the client.

Can someone please help me with what I am doing wrong or otherwise guide how to do this in other ways

Server code

```
import socket                   
import time
import os

port = 6004              
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)             
host = socket.gethostname()     # Get local machine name
s.bind((host, port))            # Bind to the port
s.listen(5)                     # Now wait for client connection.

print ('Server listening....')
conn, addr = s.accept()
print ('Got connection from', addr)
# data = conn.recv(1024)
# print('Server received', repr(data))

start =time.time()

for i in range(2):
    filename="sc" + str(i) + ".jpg"
    size = str(os.path.getsize(filename))
    try:
        conn.send(size.encode())
    except:
        print('ckckckckckck')
    print('filesize', size, len(size))
    f = open(filename,'rb')
    current=0
    size = int(size)
    while current <size:
       l = f.read(1024)
       conn.send(l)
       current+=len(l)
       print('current',current)
       print('l',len(l))
       if(current==size):
        break
    print('close current',current)
    f.close()

print('Done sending')
conn.send(b'Thank you for connecting')
#conn.close()
print(time.time()-start)
```

Client code

```
import os
import socket 
import time                 # Import socket module

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)             # Create a socket object
host = socket.gethostname()     # Get local machine name
port = 6004               # Reserve a port for your service.

s.connect((host, port))
s.send(b'Hello server!')

for i in range(2):
    data = None
    data = s.recv(1024)
    data = data.decode()
    size = int(data)
    print(size)
    filename = "sc" + str(i) + ".jpg"
    f = open(filename,'wb')
    current =0
    while current<size:
        data = s.recv(1024)
        f.write(data)
        current+=len(data)
        # print('data',len(data))
        # print('current',current)
        if(current==size):
            break
    print('close current',current)
    f.close()
print('Successfully get the file')
s.close()
print('connection closed')
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>   data = s.recv(5)
> ```

You expect that the size is within the first 5 bytes and you expect to get it with one `recv`. But, the actual size can be less than 5 bytes or more since you don't enforce a specific number of bytes when sending:

> ```
>     conn.send(size.encode())
> ```

Thus what could happen here is that the size you read in the client is either too small (if the original size was larger) or that the size used less than 5 bytes and there are already data from the file contents within the 5 bytes you read. And this causes the error you see.

Note that TCP is a byte-stream protocol and not a message protocol, which means that what you `send` is not necessarily what you `recv`. Instead the data from multiple `send` could be read within one `recv` or a single `send` could make multiple `recv` necessary. Thus a better design of your code would make sure that it always writes a fixed length for the length and always makes sure that it got the full length before trying to interpret the data as length.

Comment: sorry that **data = s.recv(5)** is written by mistake.But what actually happening is that the two send calls are merging together and returning the single read can you please help how can i resolve that

Comment: @siddharthshrivastava: to cite myself: *"... TCP is a byte-stream protocol and not a message protocol, which means that __what you send is not necessarily what you recv__..."* and *"... a better design of your code would make sure that it __always writes a fixed length__ for the length and always __makes sure that it got the full length__ before trying to interpret the data as length."*

Comment: So if I use UDP in place of TCP will this problem get resolved. but when I tried with udp the single recvfrom returns the data from multiple send() can you please help me with this I actually want to send multiple images from server to client is there another way to do this.

Comment: @siddharthshrivastava: I've explicitly highlighted the relevant points in my comment. It is not clear for me what you don't understand since you don't even address anything I've said. Instead you just ask for help without saying where exactly you need help.